# wsdl java import problem

Tags: java, wsdl

```
import com.premiereconnect.premconn.FaxNumberAvailableListRequest;
import com.premiereconnect.premconn.FaxNumberAvailableListResult;
import com.premiereconnect.premconn.GroupListResult;
import com.premiereconnect.premconn.UserCreateRequest;
import com.premiereconnect.premconn.UserCreateResult;
import com.premiereconnect.premconn.UserUpdateRequest;
import com.premiereconnect.premconn.UserUpdateResult;
```

The above imported classes are in wsdl file.. how to generate packages "comm.premiereconnect.premconn"....
A url for wsdl file is also given... How to generate/ resolve this import issue

Comment: You'll need to do better than that. Information, context, please.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [J2EE 5 SDK](http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/?intcmp=1282) or the [JDK 6](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/?intcmp=1281), they comes with a tool named [wsimport](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) that can be used to generate JAX-WS proxy classes from a wsdl file or url.

```
wsimport -s src -d build -p com.premiereconnect.premconn -keep my.wsdl
```

will process my.wsdl and create source files in `src/com/priemiereconnect/premconn` and binary files in `build/com/premiereconnect/premconn` both in the package `com.premiereconnect.premconn`

my.wsdl can be a url or a file.

*Coincidentally* the directories used above are the ones used by Eclipse for its projects' source and binary files. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use Axis' WSDL2Java on the WSDL to create the classes.

Answer (score 0):

As stevedbrown said [WSDL2Java](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL) will do the job for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use axis2-1.5.5\bin\wsdl2java or apache-cxf-2.5.2\bin\wsdl2java -autoNameResolution could solve your problem.
However, I don't know the underhood about this name conflict.